# Reason behind CIFAR dataset fixed image size

Tags: image-processing

What is the reason behind having the size of the CIFAR dataset images fixed at 32X32? Is it just that the size is small enough to enable training to be completed in decent time?

Answer (score 0):

They're a subset of "80 million tiny images: a large dataset for non-parametric object and scene recognition (A. Torralba, R. Fergus, W. T. Freeman)". That set is already approximately 300 Gb at its current resolution.